# Can you convolve two generelized functions? how?

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, convolution, cauchy-principal-value

By generalized functions I mean functionals from $C^\infty_c(U)\to \mathbb{R}$ as defined in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).
I want to compute:

$$ \operatorname{comb}(\omega)*\operatorname{pv}(\frac{1}{\omega}) $$

But the operation is a convolution between two generalized functions. Generally speaking, only linear operations can be extended from the regular functions into the generalized functions, but despite that it is very natural to say:

$$\operatorname{comb}(\omega)*\operatorname{pv}(\frac{1}{\omega}) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \operatorname{pv}(\frac{1}{\omega-n})$$

As that is the way a convolution with $\operatorname{comb}$ affects regular functions. Another way to "compute" this expression without convolving distributions is by:

$$ \mathcal{F}(\operatorname{comb}(\omega)*\operatorname{pv}(\frac{1}{\omega})) = \mathcal{F}(\operatorname{comb}(\omega))\cdot \mathcal{F}(\operatorname{pv}(\frac{1}{\omega}))$$

Where here the Fourier transform of the Cauchy principal value is (proportional to) the sign function, which is a regular function.

I'm aware that more expansive definitions of generalized functions exist, that for example allow multiplication. That fact is mentioned [on this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function). Sadly, I don't have access to their source article so I don't know what those definitions are or if they help me solve my problem.

Is the calculation I want to do allowed? How could I calculate it formally?

Comment: The definition of convolution of two distributions $u,v$ is 
$$\langle u*v, \varphi \rangle := \langle u(x)\otimes v(y), \varphi(x+y) \rangle$$
for each test function $\varphi.$